# How to only get date and time in kendo stock chart tooltip

Tags: kendo-ui

Hai,
                       I have configured kendo stock chart.In that I am getting a problem with tool tip .how to get the customize  tool tip with date like 1/2/2012 3:12:13

```
function createChart() {
            $("#stock-chart").kendoStockChart({
                dataSource: {
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/StockData",
                            dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
                        parameterMap: function(data) {
                            return { filter: JSON.stringify(data.filter) };
                        }
                    },
                    schema: stockDataSchema
                },
                title: {
                    text: "The ACME Company"
                },
                dateField: "Date",
                series: [{
                    type: "column",
                    field: "Open"

                }],
               tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                 template: "Time:${category} - Mode:${value}"

        },
                navigator: {
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/StockData",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            }
                        },
                        schema: stockDataSchema
                    },
                    series: {
                        type: "column",
                        field: "High"
                    },
                    select: {
                        from: "2009/02/05",
                        to: "2011/10/07"
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
```

Here is the working Js Fiddle:http://jsbin.com/ilemel/54/edit

Answer (score 3):

Try with this,

Demo:http://jsbin.com/ilemel/56/edit

```
tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                 template: "Time:#= kendo.format('{0:dd/MM/yyyy}',category) # - Mode:${value}"

        },
```

Comment: how to read time .I have configured like this dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss. But not reading seconds and minutes

Comment: Try this, `0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss` read this http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: 0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss .It was displaying only mins How to enable all the three like hours minu and secs

Comment: try this, `{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss}`

Comment: no change in hours and seconds .I am not getting, from where the value has been taken .Constantly the hour vale is reading as 12 and min as 1,2,3,4... and secs as 0 only